# Threaded Core Data Confuse Implement

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data

Lately, i've been digging quite a lot about Threaded CoreData, I'v read these tutorials:

- ZACoreData
- [issue-10-core-data-network-application](https://github.com/objcio/issue-10-core-data-network-application)

Personally, i happy with ZACoreData ways. Cause it stick to apple rules. That create a single context for each thread.

```
    + (NSManagedObjectContext *) contextForCurrentThread
{
    if (!_managedObjectContextsDictionary) {
        _managedObjectContextsDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }

    // Force the return of the main thread context.
    if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
        return [NSManagedObjectContext contextForMainThread];
    }

    NSThread *currentThread = [NSThread currentThread];
    if (![[currentThread name] length]) {
        [currentThread setName: [NSManagedObjectContext generateGUID]];

        NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType contextType = ([currentThread isMainThread]) ? NSMainQueueConcurrencyType : NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType;

        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType: contextType];

        if ([currentThread isMainThread]) {
            context.persistentStoreCoordinator = [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator sharedPersisntentStoreCoordinator];
        }

        if (![currentThread isMainThread]) {
            context.parentContext = [NSManagedObjectContext contextForMainThread];
        }
        [_managedObjectContextsDictionary setObject:context forKey: [currentThread name]];

        return context;
    } else {
        return [_managedObjectContextsDictionary objectForKey: [currentThread name]];
    }
}
```

But my boss doesn't want to implement like this, he prefer using issue-10-core-data-network-application, which this demo doesn't even work cause their webservice can not run. And they init both Main Thread Context and BackgroundThread Context in main thread. After that they just pass the backgroundContext for use in Background.

```
- (void)setupManagedObjectContexts
{
    self.managedObjectContext = [self setupManagedObjectContextWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    self.managedObjectContext.undoManager = [[NSUndoManager alloc] init];

    self.backgroundManagedObjectContext = [self setupManagedObjectContextWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    self.backgroundManagedObjectContext.undoManager = nil;


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
            addObserverForName:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                        object:nil
                         queue:nil
                    usingBlock:^(NSNotification* note) {
        NSManagedObjectContext *moc = self.managedObjectContext;
        if (note.object != moc) {
            [moc performBlock:^(){
                [moc mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:note];
            }];
        }
     }];
}
```

And they use like this:

```
- (void)import
{
    self.batchCount = 0;
    [self.webservice fetchAllPods:^(NSArray *pods)
    {
        [self.context performBlock:^
        {
            for(NSDictionary *podSpec in pods) {
                NSString *identifier = [podSpec[@"name"] stringByAppendingString:podSpec[@"version"]];
                Pod *pod = [Pod findOrCreatePodWithIdentifier:identifier inContext:self.context];
                [pod loadFromDictionary:podSpec];
            }
            self.batchCount++;
            if (self.batchCount % 10 == 0) {
                NSError *error = nil;
                [self.context save:&error];
                if (error) {
                    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                }
            }
        }];
    }];
}
```

personally, I think the way issue-10-core-data-network-application implement is totally wrong and not follow with apple rules which is we must create each background thread a NSManageObjectContext. Is it right? Please give me your opinion. Which way implement right?.

Answer (score 0):

Managed object contexts created with a private queue can be created on the main thread and then used elsewhere. The important part is that the contents of the context (or any object fetched from the context) can only be used inside a `performBlock`, because that code is run on the thread associated with the private queue of the context (and this is the key point about the original dictat that contexts not be shared across threads).

Comment: Thanks men. Now it become more clear to me with the tutorial two.

Comment: No problem, please vote and tick questions that helped and solved your question ;-)